# Adding a scrollbar to a panelgrid in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a panel grid having 50 columns atleast but during display all the columns in the UI gets congested. I tried the properties which i could but to no avail. 
Below is my code. any help is appreciated.

```
<p:panel>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Search Results" style="font-weight: bold;"></h:outputLabel>

                    <p:dataTable scrollWidth="100%" id="SearchResult" var="SearchResult"
                        value="beanId" style="width:100%;"
                        selection="beanId"
                        rowKey="beanId" scrollable="true"
                        rowSelectMode="multiple" scrollHeight="100%">
                        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:5%;" />

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Year" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="MbeanValue" />
                        </p:column> 

                        |
                        |
                        |
                        |
                        similarly upto 50 columns
                </p:panel>
```

Answer (score 8):

A `p:panel` generates a `<div/>` so the `overflow-y` CSS style attribute will work :

```
<p:panel  style="float:left;overflow-y: auto;height: 100px;">
```

The `height` attrbute specifies the point at which the div should break into a scrollbar

Comment: Thanks nice solution.